# wx.PasswordEntryDialog prevent resizing

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wx.PasswordEntryDialog and I want to prevent it from being resized by the user.

What I've tried:

```
dialog = wx.PasswordEntryDialog(self, "Insert password", "",
                                            style=wx.TextEntryDialogStyle ^ (wx.RESIZE_BORDER |
                                                                             wx.RESIZE_BOX |
                                                                             wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
```

Comment: remove the resize_border flag

Comment: Well this is the idea, to remove to remove RESIZE_BORDER from the style, thus to prevent from being resized. But not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
size = dialog.GetSize()
dialog.SetMinSize(size)
dialog.SetMaxSize(size)
```

**EDIT:**

Calling dialog.SetWindowStyle after initialization worked for me

```
dialog.SetWindowStyle(wx.CAPTION)
```

Comment: The resize sign still appears, but you can't resize it. If I could also remove that it would be perfect.

Comment: calling SetStyle after the dialog is created seems to work

Comment: I'm using wxPython3.0, when I call dialog.SetStyle(wx.CAPTION), on a wx.PasswordEntryDialog, I get AttributeError: 'PasswordEntryDialog' object has no attribute 'SetStyle'.

Comment: whoops, should have written SetWindowStyle